# Xamarin Forms: How do I implement WebSockets?

Tags: xamarin, websocket, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

We want to transfer data from a client to a server in realtime, so we have decided to go with WebSockets.

Using Xamarin.Forms it was surprisingly difficult to find a suitable WebSocket library.

The best match was "WebSocket4Net" because it is directly suggested on Xamarin's Homepage. However I was not able to install this library, because it only supports versions of .NET up to v4.0. (We are using v4.5)

Whenever I try to change the target framework of my PCLs from v4.5 to v4.0 I get loads of weird errors stating "Windows.Input library could not be found", "ObservableCollection could not be found" etc.

So we are currently using the library "WebSocket.Portable.Core", which although lacking some functionality worked out. However for some reason we can only receive one message. The event "MessageReceived" always is just called once.

Has anyone heard about such a problem with WebSockets? Maybe it is just time to use another library, but I just can't find one?

I also can't find any solution how to implement WebSockets natively for each platform.

Comment: Are you able to use `System.Net.WebSockets`? Looking through some documentation, I found it [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/namespace/System.Net.WebSockets/).

Comment: That is the most confusing thing of all. I would love to use that, because this seems like a adequately developed library. But I can not find ANY reference to this anywhere. I can't add a reference, I don't find anything like it in nuget package manager etc.

Comment: After lots of searching I have found SOME hint that PCLs (at least put into the context of xamarin) only support the most basic functionalities of .NET
So to answer your question. No? At least I couldn't figure out how

Comment: You'll need to import System.Net as a library into your project to get it to work.

Comment: Just to make sure that we do talk of the dame thing here. PCLs in xamarin are reduced PCLs so not everything which would sork on other systems actually works here. I do have a reference to system.net.http.extensions and system.net.http.primitives there is no other option. When I click on add reference it states that "All of the frameworks are already referenced."

Comment: Give me a minute, I'll download Xamarin Studio and try this out myself.

Comment: Yes thank you very much for your time and considerstion :)

Comment: I am using visual studio (if that mstters)

Comment: Oh, weird; have you tried importing your project to Xamarin Studio? I imagine there would be some annoying clash which .NET core libraries to use when you're building your project against Xamarin libraries in Visual Studio. If this is not an option, I'll see if I can figure it out.

Comment: Does it work in xamarin studio? Because I am used to visual studio so I didnt want to use xamarin studio which I thought is much less developed than VS I would need to ibstallt it

Comment: FYI: WebSocket4Net does not have PCL support (yet...), there is an open issue regarding this as this library is highly platform dependent @ https://github.com/kerryjiang/WebSocket4Net/issues/14 If you did want to use this lib right now, you would have to add it to each of your platform targeted projects (iOS, Android, etc.. but not the Forms project. You could than add your own interface to them within your Forms project

Comment: Could you please provide an example of this as an answer? I think this is the solution but I hwve no idea how to implement some logic separate in each plstform dependent project and then reuse it in xamarin forms. If you could point a finger in tbe right direction or provide an abstract example of this case I would be very glad.

Comment: agree; very frustrating seeing the documentation (https://developer.xamarin.com/api/namespace/System.Net.WebSockets) but no idea what nuget package to add to my project.

Comment: Found this: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.WebSockets.Client/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebSockets.PCL has a native implementation for each platform and it's well documented

https://github.com/NVentimiglia/WebSockets.Pcl

Comment: I have come across this library but for some reason I couldn't get it to work with the references.

Comment: Anyway its is irrelevant now because we changed to native coding.

Comment: For future viewers [this tutorial](http://fullstackmark.com/post/3/websockets-with-aspnet-core-and-xamarin-forms) implements WebSockets.Pcl in XF with example code.