# Get WebSocket with HttpListener

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, websocket

I'm "porting" asp.net server to xamarin.forms (Android)

I'm using HttpListener and trying to get WebSocket from the connection

HttpListenerContext.Request.IsWebSocketRequest is always false and

HttpListenerContext.AcceptWebSocketAsync throws NotImplementedException

I tried to use WebSocket.CreateFromStream and WebSocket.CreateClientWebSocket with HttpListenerContext.Request.InputStream as the stream, but I get WebSocketException (remote party closed WebSocket connection without completing the close handshake) when calling ReceiveAsync

Comment: HttpListenerContext.Request.IsWebSocketRequest being false means that the TCP connection is not a WebSocket request. You said that you get WebSocketException (remote party closed WebSocket connection without completing the close handshake) when calling ReceiveAsync, are you using a prime key? Otherwise, it won't work.

Comment: It is websocket request (Connection: Upgrade, Upgrade: websocket + plus it is true in the asp.net version), I have also figured out that it isn't implement in mono, is there some alternative to it?

Comment: You can see this case: [Xamarin Forms: How do I implement WebSockets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34820619/xamarin-forms-how-do-i-implement-websockets). Wish it can help you.